# How do I fix RN GoogleSignin module linking.

Tags: react-native

Every time I use Yarn everything blows up, which are the instructions given by the react-native-community.

I've tried just doing the npm install --save and then use the link command but nothing works so far.

What am i doing wrong? and how do i fix this.

```
onsole.error: "RN GoogleSignin native module is not correctly linked. Please read the readme, setup and troubleshooting instructions carefully or try manual linking."
```

Comment: sometime react-native link doesn't work, so you have to link the library manually

Comment: In my case, under iOS, the issue was caused by a failure of the tooling to link libRNGoogleSignin.a properly.  I deleted the flawed entry and manually executed step three under **Link the native module** > In XCode, in the project navigator, select your project. Add libRNGoogleSignin.a to your project's Build Phases ➜ Link Binary With  Libraries

Comment: I gave up on THE react googlesignin stuff after 2 days of tinkering.. I just followed the freebase guide and everything works.

Comment: Hi guys i have the same issue, i have been stuck on this issue for three days.
I have tried a lot of things (auto-linking,........), but with no success, can you please share more details (for my case my version of react native is  0.63.4, react is 17.0.1, @react-native-google-signin/google-signin 6.0.0, cocapods 1.10.1)

Comment: for me the package name in app.json -> android.package and the value in google cloud android client were not matching. Also, the SHA fingerprint was different. Once i fixed those 2 values, this error went away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave up on THE react googlesignin stuff after 2 days of tinkering.. I just followed the firebase guide and expo guide and everything works.

Expo google login gets the credentials
then firebase checks the crednetials and logs you in.

if you are doing a firebase googlelogin thing and you already have firebase setup you can do something

```
googleLogin = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
          androidClientId: "Your Client ID",
          //iosClientId: YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE,  <-- if you use iOS
          scopes: ["profile", "email"]

        })
        if (result.type === "success") {
          const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(result.idToken, result.accessToken);
             firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(function(result){
               console.log(result);
             });
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Where you want to go');
   } else {
     console.log("cancelled")
   }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("error", e)
      }
  }
```

Comment: Glad you got it working, however using something completely different is not much of a solution, especially not to people coming here for an answer to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I got this solved by just installing pos for the same:

**Step 1:** 
Goto the ios folder inside the app,
Check for the pod file it must be having a line

```
  pod 'RNGoogleSignin', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-google-signin'
```

if it is not pleased run the command :

```
  react-native link,
```

The above line will appear.

**Step 2:**
Now run the following command.

```
 pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

For IOS,Please add this in your Pod file and do pod install before run-ios:

pod 'RNGoogleSignin', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/google-signin'

I faced similar issue while manually upgrading react native from 0.59.9 to 0.62.2. I have also uninstalled react-native-google-signin and installed @react-native-community/google-signin before making Pod File change.

Answer (score 0):

i also faced the same error. I had installed the react-native-google-signin using the command: npm i react-native-google-signin

i tried installing it with the command: yarn add react-native-google-signin

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, try cleaning up your project using `cd android && .gradlew clean`
and then clean up the node modules folder using `rm -rf node_modules/ yarn.lock` or `Package.json.lock` if you are using npm. This might not address the issue with the package but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution work:

- Just verify if @react-native-community/google-signin is in your package.json

  > npm i @react-native-community/google-signin
- Go to your Podfile and add this line:

  > pod 'RNGoogleSignin',   :path =>  "../node_modules/@react-native-community/google-signin"

This maybe work to you.

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt the development build using `eas build --profile development --platform android`, installed development build and ran the application by scanning the QR code that appears by running `npx expo start --dev-client`. And it works fine.

Remember before using Firebase `google-service.json` file make sure you have added fingerprint on android application in firebase console, which is present under `Project Overview > General > Android apps`. Expo SHA-1 can be seen by simply running `eas credentials` > select platform > select type of build 'development/production'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just wanted to run iOS. So now I upload the module for android only:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') GoogleSignin.configure({ webClientId: config.WEB_CLIENT_ID_GOOGLE });
```